# Generating dgml files from command line

Tags: command-line, dgml

Is there a command line tool to generate the dgml file from a list of dlls?
I have tried graphcmd.exe, this only further simplifies an already generated dgml file.
Are there any command line options in the visual studio ultimate through which we can achieve this?

The reason that i ask this is, i would like to generate the dgml files as part of the continuous integration, and further process each file to get the integrated dependency graphs of all individual components involved in the system.

Answer (score 1):

GraphCmd can crack assemblies and produce DGML output.  But it cannot produce a complete top down dependency graph with groups by namespace and class and so on.  But if you use the Architecture Explorer "Select Files...", point at an assembly, select the types and members that you are interested in, then click "Save Query" in the vertical AE toolbar on the left, then open the resulting .dgql file you will see how it works.  Then you can pass this query to GraphCmd using "-query" argument.

Comment: This sounds like a doable idea! Will try this out and get back :)

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried this option. But the generated dgml file from command prompt is very different from that generated from the visual studio. Is there something very obvious that i have missed? The command line generated dgml has only the selected dll files. No information about the namespaces/classes/methods inside it.

Comment: @Rajesh any chance of you posting the cmd you're using to generate the dgml file for the DLLs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in VS 2010.  You can only generate dgml diagrams from inside VS.  If you're looking to manage your dependencies as part of your build you may want to look at [VS 2010 layer validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2008/12/11/incorporate-layer-validation-in-your-builds.aspx).